# Jordan form of $15 \times 15$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

Let $A \in M(15,15,\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix that satisfies:

1. The characteristic polynomial is $p(x)=-x^5(x-1)^5(x+1)^5$
2. The dimension of the range of $A$ is $13$ and $\dim \ker A^2=4$.
3. The dimension of the range of $A-I$ is $12$ and the minimal polynomial is $(x-1)^2q(x)$ and $q(1)\neq 0$.
4. The dimension of the range of $(A+I)^i$ is $10$ for $i\geq 5$.

How I can determinate the Jordan form of $A$?

Comment: Such a matrix cannot exist: if it has dimension $15$, its characteristic polynomial has degree $15$.

Comment: But the characteriscal polynomial has degree 15 , the characteristical polynomial is p(x)=-x^5 *(x+1)^5*(x-1)^5

Comment: Did I misread, or did you edit  it since I posted my comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- The characteristic polynomial gives you the eigenvalues, with multiplicity.
- From 2, we have $\dim \ker A$ and $\dim \ker A^2$.  $\dim \ker A$ is the number of Jordan blocks associated with $0$, and $\dim \ker A^2 - \dim \ker A$ is the number of Jordan blocks associated with $0$ that have size at least $2$.
- Similarly, $\dim \ker(A - I)$ is the number of Jordan blocks associated with $1$.  The minimal polynomial tells you that the largest Jordan block associated with $1$ has size $2$.
- I'm not sure how to interpret 4.  If the 4th point is supposed to imply that the dimension of the range of $(A + I)^4$ is strictly less than $10$, then we know that there is exactly one Jordan block associated with $-1$.  Otherwise, it gives us no new information; the fact that $(A + I)^i$ has range of dimension $10$ for all $i\geq 5$ follows from the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

- The eigenvalue $0$:

$\dim\ker A = 2$ tells you there are two Jordan blocks associated with $0$. Furthermore, $\dim\ker A^2 = 4$ tells you that both of them are of size $\ge 2$. Since the sum of their sizes has to be $5$, we conclude that there is one block of size $3$ and one of size $2$.

- The eigenvalue $1$:

$\dim\ker A = 3$ tells you there are three Jordan blocks associated with $1$. The fact $(x-1)^2 \mid\mid m_A$ implies that the size of the largest block is $2$. Since the sum of blocks' sizes has to be $5$, the only option for the block sizes is $2, 2, 1$.

- The eigevalue $-1$:

$\dim\ker(A+I)^i = 5, \forall i \ge 5$ tells you nothing, since you already know that the kernels of $(A+I)^i$ have to stablize to the maximum dimenision of $5$ when $i \ge 5$ or sooner. Therefore, you only know that the sum of the blocks' sizes is $5$ so the possibilities are the seven partitions of $5$:

\begin{align}
&5\\ 
&4,1\\
&3,2\\
&3,1,1\\
&2,2,1\\
&2,1,1,1\\
&1,1,1,1,1
\end{align}